# Custom directive not picking up model initialization

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive, angular-cookies

I have written a custom AngularJS directive that implements a toggle checkbox based on [Bootstrap Toggle](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com). I added support for [angular-translate](https://angular-translate.github.io), but that is beyond my actual proplem. Furthermore, I wanted to use [angular-cookies](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies) to save and restore the current state of a particular checkbox.

**However, my directive does not pick-up the initial value of the data model properly.**

This is my directive:

```
app.directive('toggleCheckbox', ['$rootScope', '$translate', '$timeout', function($rootScope, $translate, $timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attributes, ngModelController) {

      // Change model, when checkbox is toggled
      element.on('change.toggle', function(event) {
        var checked = element.prop('checked');
        console.log('change.toggle was called: ' + checked + ' vs. ' + ngModelController.$viewValue);
        if (checked != ngModelController.$viewValue) {
          scope.$apply(function changeViewModel() {
            ngModelController.$setViewValue(checked);
            console.log('change.toggle:', checked);
          });
        }
      });

      // Render element
      ngModelController.$render = function() {
        element.bootstrapToggle(ngModelController.$viewValue ? 'on' : 'off')
      };

      // Translate checkbox labels
      var updateLabels = function() {
        var offLabel = (attributes['off'] ? $translate.instant(attributes['off']) : 'Off');
        var onLabel  = (attributes['on']  ? $translate.instant(attributes['on'])  : 'On');

        angular.element(document).find('label.btn.toggle-off').html(offLabel);
        angular.element(document).find('label.btn.toggle-on').html(onLabel);
      };

      // Update labels, when language is changed at runtime
      $rootScope.$on('$translateChangeSuccess', function() {
        updateLabels();
      });

      // Initialize labels for the first time
      $timeout(function() {
        updateLabels();
      });

      // Clean up properly
      scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
        element.off('change.toggle');
        element.bootstrapToggle('destroy');
      });

      // Initialize element based on model
      var initialValue = scope.$eval(attributes.ngModel);
      console.log('initialValue:', initialValue);
      element.prop('checked', initialValue);
    }
  };
}]);
```

This is how I initialize the data model from cookie:

```
mainController.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$cookies', 'Main', function($scope, $cookies, Main) {

  this.$onInit = function() {
    $scope.settings.foobar = $cookies.get('foobar');
    console.log('$onInit(): ', $scope.settings.foobar);
  };

  // ...

}]);
```

And this is how I eventually use my directive:

```
<div id="foobar-switcher" ng-if="isAdmin()">
  <label for="foobar_toggle"><span translate="foobar"></span>:</label>
  <input id="foobar_toggle" type="checkbox"
    ng-model="settings.foobar" ng-change="setFoobarCookie(settings.foobar)" toggle-checkbox
    data-off="foo_label" data-offstyle="success"
    data-on="bar_label" data-onstyle="danger" />
</div>
```

Ultimately, I get this debug output:

> controllers.js:33 $onInit(): true
>
> directives.js:76 initialValue: true
>
> directives.js:37 change.toggle was called: false vs. false

So in case the value `true` is stored in the cookie, the model gets initialized properly in the global scope and even the directive uses the correct value to initialize `element`. The `change.toggle` event handler is triggered as well, but there the element's value is now `false`.

Why is that and how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that `$cookies.get('foobar')` returns a String and the checkbox cannot handle a `ng-model` of that type. Instead, the cookie value must be evaluated such, that a boolean value can be set in the data model:

```
var cookie = $cookies.get('foobar');
$scope.settings.foobar = (cookie === 'true');
```

The checkbox is then correctly initialized on page load.